# Why recursive PromiseKit functions cannot be compiled?

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, promisekit

I have next recursive Promise function call:

```
 func getPlaces(location: Location) -> Promise<[Geosearch]> {
   return Promise().then {
     URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: url)
   }.compactMap { result in
     let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonPlaces.self, from: result.data)
     let places = json.query.geosearch
     return places
   }
 }

 func getAtLeastOnePlace(location: Location) -> Promise<[Geosearch]> {
   return getPlaces(location).then{ places in      //error here
     if hasNonVisitedPlaces(places: places) {
        return Promise.value(places)
     } else {
        return getPlaces(location)
     }
   }
 }

 func hasNonVisitedPlaces(places: [Geosearch]) -> Bool {
     return places.count > 0
 }
```

But compiler failed building with error "Cannot convert return expression of type 'Promise<_.T>' to return type 'Promise<[Geosearch]>'. Where is the mistake?

---

It seems like compiler error.
This function has been compiled correctly:

```
 func getAtLeastOnePlace(location: Location) -> Promise<[Geosearch]> {
   return getPlaces(location).then{ places in                            
      return Promise.value(places)
   }
 }
```

This function too:

```
 func getAtLeastOnePlace(location: Location) -> Promise<[Geosearch]> {
   return getPlaces(location).then{ places in                            
      return getPlaces(location)
   }
 }
```

But this function caused an error:

```
 func getAtLeastOnePlace(location: Location) -> Promise<[Geosearch]> {
   return getPlaces(location).then{ places in      //error here
     if hasNonVisitedPlaces(places: places) {
        return Promise.value(places)
     } else {
        return getPlaces(location)
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: what line is the error on?

Comment: Updated with error line mark

Answer (score 0):

sometime we need to provide return type explicitly, so try below.

```
func getAtLeastOnePlace(location: Location) -> Promise<[Geosearch]> {
   return getPlaces(location).then{ places -> Promise<[Geosearch]> in
     if hasNonVisitedPlaces(places: places) {
        return Promise.value(places)
     } else {
        return getPlaces(location)
     }
   }
 }
```